# Records sorted by date appear correctly in view and stored procedure but appear out of order in PHP results

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a curious issue: PHP calls a MariaDB stored procedure that selects from an ordered view. The PHP results are sorted in a different date order as compared to running the stored procedure via command line or selecting directly from the view.

Something to do with PHP only being able to handle the date as a string, perhaps? (HTML5 date-type not compatible with required browsers.)  But I assume the data is sorted before being returned to PHP.

Thank you for reading!

Result of stored procedure through command line:

> ```
> 2017-12-01 | Attendance  |   4.00
> 2017-12-03 | Clay        |  18.00
> 2017-12-13 | Attendance  |   4.00
> **2017-12-16 | Firing      |  12.00**
> ```

Result of stored procedure called via PHP:

> ```
> Date  Transaction Amount
> 2017-12-01    Attendance  $4.00
> 2017-12-03    Clay    $18.00
> **2017-12-16  Firing  $12.00**
> 2017-12-13    Attendance  $4.00
> ```

Here's the relevant code:

SQL ordered view:

```
Create View
`view_invoices`
AS select `view_sum`.`Total` AS `Total`,
    `view_sum`.`Member_ID` AS `Member_ID`,
    `bpg`.`accounts`.`Date` AS `Date`,
    `bpg`.`accounts`.`Transaction` AS `Transaction`,
    `bpg`.`accounts`.`Amount` AS `Amount`,
    `bpg`.`members`.`First_name` AS `First_name`,
    `bpg`.`members`.`Email` AS `Email`,
    `view_member_names`.`Member_name` AS `Member_name`
from ((((select sum(`bpg`.`accounts`.`Amount`) AS `Total`,
        `bpg`.`accounts`.`Member_ID` AS `Member_ID`
        from `bpg`.`accounts`
group by `bpg`.`accounts`.`Member_ID`)
    `view_sum` join `bpg`.`accounts`)
    join `bpg`.`members`)
    join `bpg`.`view_member_names`)
where `view_sum`.`Member_ID` = `bpg`.`accounts`.`Member_ID`
and `view_sum`.`Member_ID` = `bpg`.`members`.`Member_ID`
and `view_sum`.`Member_ID` = `view_member_names`.`Member_ID`
order by `view_member_names`.`Member_name`, `accounts`.`Date`;
```

SQL stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `invoices`
    (parameter_start_date DATE
    , parameter_end_date DATE)

    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    MODIFIES SQL DATA

    BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM `view_invoices`
    WHERE `Date` >= parameter_start_date
    AND `Date` <= parameter_end_date
    ;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

PHP call:

```
<?php

function invoices($start_date, $end_date) {
        require LIB_DIR . '\pdo.php';

        // in development
        ini_set('display_errors',1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $prev = NULL;
    $intro = "<body style='background-color:#f0f2f4;font-family:Calibri,Verdana,Arial;'>";
    $intro .= "<ul style='float:left;list-style-type:none;width:100%;background-color:#d3d9de;'>";
    $intro .=    "<li style='display:inline;float:left;border-width:10px;border-color:#d3d9de;padding:5px;margin:5px;background-color:#FEFEFE;align-self:center;'>";
    $intro .= "<img src='PATH\public\images\BPG_logo_big.png' height='166' width='173'></li>";
    $intro .= "<li style='display:inline;float:left;border:5px;border-color:#d3d9de;margin:5px;padding:5px;background-color:#FEFEFE;width:250px;height:166px;align-self:center;text-indent:5pxeach-line;'>";
    $intro .= "<h2>Invoice</h2>";
    $intro .= "<p style='margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:0px;'>39 Elizabeth Street<br>Cloverdale WA 6076<br>treasurerbpg@gmail.com</p></li></ul>";

    $outro = "<p style='margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:0px;'>You can pay by direct deposit, at your bank, or by cheque using the details below.</p>";
    $outro .= "<p style='font-weight:bold;margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:0px;'>Please use your name as the payment reference. </p>";   

    $sql = "CALL invoices (:start_date, :end_date)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':start_date', $start_date);
    $stmt->bindValue(':end_date', $end_date);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bindColumn('Total', $total);
    $stmt->bindColumn('Member_ID', $id);
    $stmt->bindColumn('Date', $date);
    $stmt->bindColumn('Transaction', $transaction);
    $stmt->bindColumn('Amount', $amount);
    $stmt->bindColumn('First_name', $fname);
    $stmt->bindColumn('Email', $email);
    $stmt->bindColumn('Member_name', $name);

    $message = NULL;
    $curr_date = date("Y.m.d");
    $due_date = strtotime("+7 day");
    $due_date = date('j F Y', $due_date);
    $curr_date_words = date('j F Y');
    $start_date_words = strtotime($start_date);
    $start_date_words = date('j F Y', $start_date_words);
    $end_date_words = strtotime($end_date);
    $end_date_words = date('j F Y', $end_date_words);
    $filename = NULL;
    $number = $stmt->rowCount();
    echo $number;

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {

        $number = --$number;
        $person = $id;

        if ($person != $prev) {    // if the current member is different from the previous member, print header and row

            if ($row > 0) {
                $message .= "</table>"; /*added line of code*/
                $message .= $outro;


                if($filename != NULL) {
                    $savedfile = fopen(WRITE_DIR . $filename, "w") or die("File BPG_invoice_" . $filename . ".html was not created.");
                    fwrite($savedfile, $message);
                    fclose($savedfile);
                    echo $filename . " was saved here: " . WRITE_DIR . "<br>";
                }

          }


    // file name

            $filename = "\BPG_invoice_" . $curr_date . "_" . $name . ".html";
    // message
            $message = $intro;

            $message .= "<br><br><p style='margin-left:15px;'>Member: " . $name . "<br>";
            $message .= "Date: " . $curr_date_words . "</p>";
            $message .= "<p style='margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:0px;'><br>Dear " . $fname . "</p>";
            $message .= "<p style='margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:0px;'>Please find your fees for the period " . $start_date_words . " to " . $end_date_words . " below. </p>";
            $message .= "<p style='margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:0px;font-size:1.6em;font-weight:bold;'>The total of your invoice is: $" . $total . "</p>";


        if($total <= 0 ) {
            $message .= "<p style='margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:0px;'>Your account is in credit and does not require payment.</p>";
        }else{
            $message .= "<p style='margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:0px;'>Please pay before: " . $due_date . "</p>";
        }

            $message .= "<br><table style='margin-left:15px;width:350px;border-width:1px;border:solid;border:black;'><tr><th  style='padding:5px;text-align:center;'>Date</th><th style='padding:5px;text-align:center;'>Transaction</th><th style='padding:5px;text-align:center;'>Amount</th></tr>";

    // table rows

            $message .= "<tr><td style='padding:5px;text-align:center;'>" . $date . "</td>";
            $message .= "<td style='padding:5px;text-align:center;'>" . $transaction . "</td>";
            $message .= "<td style='padding:5px;text-align:center;'>$" . $amount . "</td></tr>";

    // separate if statement because || or was not working - DUPLICATED
        if($number == 0) {
    //        last_row();

                $message .= "</table>";
                $message .= $outro;

                $savedfile = fopen(WRITE_DIR . $filename, "w") or die("File BPG_invoice_" . $filename . ".html was not created.");
                fwrite($savedfile, $message);
                fclose($savedfile);
                echo $filename . " was saved here: " . WRITE_DIR . "<br>";
       }           


            $prev = $person;

        }else{

            $message .= "<tr><td style='padding:5px;text-align:center;'>" . $date . "</td>";
            $message .= "<td style='padding:5px;text-align:center;'>" . $transaction . "</td>";
            $message .= "<td style='padding:5px;text-align:center;'>$" . $amount . "</td></tr>";

            $prev = $person;

// separate if statement because || or was not working - DUPLICATED
        if($number == 0) {
        //    last_row();

                $message .= "</table>";
                $message .= $outro;

                $savedfile = fopen(WRITE_DIR . $filename, "w") or die("File BPG_invoice_" . $filename . ".html was not created.");
                fwrite($savedfile, $message);
                fclose($savedfile);
                echo $filename . " was saved here: " . WRITE_DIR . "<br>";         
            }           

        }

    }
    $message .= "</table>";
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without an `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` statement that returns the result, MySQL/MariaDB can return rows in any order and be within the spec. (It's valid for the server to ignore the `ORDER BY` clause  in the view definition.)

As far as the difference in behavior between PHP and the command line client, that's a little odd (assuming that we are connecting to the same database, same credentials, calling the same procedure.)

Comment: I wasn't aware that table sorting could be ignored. Thanks. (And yes, all other factors are identical.)